# BrowserStackLocal.exe suddenly stops. Windows 10

Tags: ui-testing, browserstack

While running some UI tests with selenium, I am running BrowserStackLocal.exe and I use this command: 
BrowserStackLocal.exe --key *browser stack license*

And everything seems to run pretty good but after around half an hour, the process suddenly stops making my selenium tests fail because they can't reach the target URL.

I am running a windows 10 machine.

Has anyone experienced this before?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you isolate/identify and exact test that causes the process to crash, from the logs or test output for example?

Comment: This points to connectivity issues with the BrowserStackLocal app. You should get this checked with BrowserStack's support team since they would have connection logs for this.

Comment: The problem is that I can't see any logs and eventviewer doesn't show anything. ;(